# Creating Sub-Levels in Hangman Using Python

Tags: python

i need help in creating sub levels in this hangman game small project that i am doing for school. someone already helped me with this but now my teacher wants sub levels too. but for those sub levels he wants a different group of words. so basically the words below are for easy, medium and hard. and then the sub levels are easy 1, easy 2 and easy 3. same for medium and then same for hard. i have already done easy 1, medium 1 and hard 1. the sub levels which are left are 2 and 3. can anyone help please? hope this makes sense. thank you so much.

```
import time
import random

#words

hardWords = ['triskaidekaphobia', 'spaghettification', 'sesquipedalian', 'floccinaucinihilipilification', 'deipnosophist']
medWords = ['erubescent', 'entomophogy', 'noctambulist', 'parapente', 'umbriferous']
simpWords = ['cat', 'house', 'degust', 'glaikit', 'otalgia']

# Just use one word, which will be set after user selects difficulty
#simpWordsR = random.choice(simpWords)
#medWordsR = random.choice(medWords)
#hardWordsR = random.choice(hardWords)


#welcome the user

name = input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello! " + name + ". Time to play Hangman")

#wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)

print ("")

# Removed uppercase. We will only use lower case
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#picking levels

gameMode = input('Choose a level - Easy (10 Guesses), Medium (8 Guesses) or Hard (7 Guesses)').lower()
if gameMode == 'easy':
    numberOfGuesses = 11
    theWord = random.choice(simpWords)
    # Not sure what this is for....deleted
    #correctLetters = ''
    #for i in range(len(simpWordsR)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    #  if simpWordsR[i] in correctLetters:
    #    blanks = blanks[:i] + simpWordsR[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    #print (blanks)

elif gameMode == 'medium':
    numberOfGuesses = 8
    theWord = random.choice(medWords)

else:
    numberOfGuesses = 7
    theWord = random.choice(hardWords)

print(gameMode)
print(theWord)  # For debugging purposes

# Since python strings are immutable, use a list
blanks = ['_'] * len(theWord)

# Need to keep a list of already guessed letters
used_letters = []

time.sleep(1)

print ("")

# Move this to the loop
#numberOfGuesses1 -= 1
#print (numberOfGuesses1)

#while numberOfGuesses1 == 10:
while numberOfGuesses > 0:
    print (numberOfGuesses)
    print (' '.join(blanks))

    # get user input and convert to lower case
    guess = input("Guess a Character!").lower()

    # Make sure it's a letter
    if not guess in alphabet:
        print("Enter a letter...")
    # Make sure not already guessed
    elif guess in used_letters:
        print("Already guessed that....")
    # Valid guess. Check it
    else:
        used_letters.append(guess)
        if (guess in theWord):
            print ("Well Done! You Guessed it right!")
            # Loop through and replace
            for x in range(0, len(theWord)):
                if theWord[x] == guess:
                    # Note: this works since theWord and blanks have the same length
                    blanks[x] = guess
            # Check for success
            if not '_' in blanks:
                print("You win")
                # End the loop
                break
        else:
            print ("The letter is not in the word. Try Again!")
            # Only decrement if incorrect
            numberOfGuesses -= 1

print ("Game Finished. Maybe Try Again y/n.")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Any chance of condensing that to a [mcve]?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  You've already done a 3-level game.  Now your instructor wants a 9-level game.  What's the problem with simply expanding your current code in the same way, just as you did in moving from 1 level to 3?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the place for asking people to do your homework for you. That said, you have a couple options.

1. Just as you created your lists, just create more lists and more elif branches.
2. A better option would be to consolidate logic chunks into reusable methods.
   This will clean up your code and allow you to be more versatile in later changes as needed.
3. Even better than that consolidate the methods and variables into classes which will make this game even simpler to implement.

Though, the 'quick' option in this case is the first option.